How to Send a Streaming Response via LlamaIndex to a FastAPI Endpoint?
I need to send a streaming response using LlamaIndex to my FastAPI endpoint. Below is the code I've written so far:
@bot_router.post("/bot/pdf_convo")
async def pdf_convo(query: QuestionInput):
    chat_engine = cache["chat_engine"]
    user_question = query.content
    streaming_response = chat_engine.stream_chat(user_question)
    for token in streaming_response.response_gen:
        print(token, end="")

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to properly implement the streaming response with LlamaIndex. Thank you!

Reference
FastAPI - StreamingResponse
Solution
In order to use the StreamingResponse class provided, you'll need to create an async generator or a normal generator/iterator, then pass it into the StreamingResponse object. In your case, you want to pass the streaming_response.response_gen into a function that will return a generator. For example, this is how I would do it:
async def response_streamer(response):
    for token in response:
        yield f"{token}"

@bot_router.post("/bot/pdf_convo")
async def pdf_convo(query: QuestionInput):
    chat_engine = cache["chat_engine"]
    user_question = query.content
    streaming_response = chat_engine.stream_chat(user_question)
    return StreamingResponse(response_streamer(streaming_response.response_gen))


I think would be better to propagate the stream as
return StreamingResponse(streaming_response.response_gen)
means without response_streamer
